# Does a k-connected graph contain a k-connected bipartite subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, graph-connectivity

I have a problem where, when trying to solve it, I use some parts which would prove that a k-connected graph contains a k-connected bipartite subgraph. I am fairly sure that this can not be correct, does someone see how my approach is wrong or is this implication true?

The proof for the statement would look somewhat like that: Take a $k$-connected graph $G$ and a bipartite subgraph $H$ of $G$ that is maximally-connected. Assume it is not $k$-connected, thus there is a set of vertices $C$ in $H$ with $c:=|C|<k$ where $H-C$ is not connected. Because the removal of $C$ disconnects $H$, there are two vertices $x, y$ in $H$ that are the only vertices connected to $C$. Because $H$ is bipartite and there exists a path of length 3 from $x$ to $y$, $x$ and $y$ are in the same partition $A$ and $C$ is contained in $B$.

Because $G$ was $k$-connected, there was a subset $C'$ in $G \backslash H$ with $|C\cup C'|=k$ and $C\cup C'$ disconnects $G$ and which is also connected to $x$ and $y$. Because the vertices in $C'$ are no longer connected to $x$ and $y$ (otherwise $H$ would be $|C\cup C'|=k$-connected), we have that $C'\subset A$.

This means that we can reconstruct $H$ by moving the vertices of $C'$ to $B$ and reconnecting $C'$ to $x$ and $y$, thus increasing the connectivity of $H$ to $|C \cup C'|=k$, which contradicts the maximality of the connectivity of $H$.

Again, does someone see where my proof is wrong or is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cliques. Clique sums of cliques. Take two copies of $K_{10}$ and sum them over $K_{8}$ and analyze. This is a collision of loved areas in research, what are the maximal properties we can attain from bipartite subgraphs? and given connectivity conditions of a graph what can we say about its subgraphs? so a google search will probably be fruitful to learning much towards your question, however, I am guessing the claim you want to show is rarely even close to true.

As for issues with the proof, there are a few. First, when taking an arbitrary subset $C$ to disconnect $H$, it is hard to impose structure, there could be many components and even possibly in different parts. Next, the argument of saying that a separating set for $H$ extends to a separating set for $G$ is not always going to be true. (This example doesn't take bipartite into consideration but demonstrates the concern -- imagine your subgraph $H$ was a clique sum, and highly connected into one side of the whole graph $G$ which is a clique sum where the two clique sums of $G$ and $H$ are disjoint. The natural separating sets are the clique sums -- NOW THIS DOESN'T NECESSARILY MEAN YOUR CLAIM IS FALSE! but see that you DO have to be careful in arguing your claim and I'm willing to bet in general it is false though a nice idea). I will leave you with these comments and allow you to think some and return.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simple counterexample though. Take any odd-length cycle [such as a 3-cycle]--which is 2 connected. What must every bipartite subgraph be.